# Cannot login when i try to delay login

Tags: php, mysql

I was trying to make delay in login for all user that failed 3 times for login. when user failed 3 times delay 1 minute, 4 times become 5 minute.
**the problem is when user failed 3 times and delay 1 minute. after 1 minute user cannot login, even the time add become delay 5 minute and continue, it continue select the delay $time.** sorry my english.
can u analysis wrong code ?

Table :
PEOPLE

Field :

PRSN_ID,SEC_KEY, PRSN_NBR, PWD, LOGIN_ATT_NBR, LOGIN_TS

CODE:

```
 if($password!=''){
    $query = "  SELECT
                LOGIN_ATT_NBR,
                LOGIN_TS,
                CASE 
                WHEN LOGIN_ATT_NBR < 3 THEN 0
                WHEN LOGIN_ATT_NBR = 3 THEN 1
                WHEN LOGIN_ATT_NBR = 4 THEN 5
                WHEN LOGIN_ATT_NBR = 5 THEN 10
        ELSE 24 END AS LMT_TM,
        CASE 
            WHEN LOGIN_ATT_NBR < 3 THEN LOGIN_TS
            WHEN LOGIN_ATT_NBR = 3 THEN LOGIN_TS + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE
            WHEN LOGIN_ATT_NBR = 4 THEN LOGIN_TS + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE
            WHEN LOGIN_ATT_NBR = 5 THEN LOGIN_TS + INTERVAL 10 MINUTE
        ELSE LOGIN_TS + INTERVAL 24 MINUTE END AS LGN_TM,
        CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS NOW
        FROM CMP.PEOPLE 
        WHERE PRSN_ID='".$loginUserID."' AND DATE(LOGIN_TS) = CURRENT_DATE";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        $rows   = mysql_fetch_array($result);

        if($rows['LOGIN_ATT_NBR'] < 3){
        $time   = "";
        }else if($rows['LOGIN_ATT_NBR'] == 3){
            $time   = "AND NOW() > LOGIN_TS + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE";
        }else if($rows['LOGIN_ATT_NBR'] == 4){
            $time   = "AND NOW() > LOGIN_TS + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE";
        }else if($rows['LOGIN_ATT_NBR'] == 5){
            $time   = "AND NOW() > LOGIN_TS + INTERVAL 10 MINUTE";
        }else{
            $time   = "AND NOW() > LOGIN_TS + INTERVAL 24 HOURS";
        }

$query="SELECT SEC_KEY,PRSN_NBR,PWD,LOGIN_ATT_NBR,LOGIN_TS FROM CMP.PEOPLE PPL INNER JOIN CMP.POS_TYP POS ON PPL.POS_TYP=POS.POS_TYP WHERE PRSN_ID ='".$loginUserID."' AND (PWD='".$password."' OR PWD='".hash('sha512',$password)."') AND TERM_DTE IS NULL".$time;

        $result=mysql_query($query);
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
        if(mysql_num_rows($result)==0){

        if($rows['LOGIN_ATT_NBR'] > 3 && ($rows['NOW'] >= $rows['LMT_TM'] ))
        {
            $query  = "UPDATE CMP.PEOPLE SET LOGIN_TS = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, LOGIN_ATT_NBR = LOGIN_ATT_NBR + 1 WHERE PRSN_ID='".$loginUserID."'";
            $result = mysql_query($query);
        }else
        {
            $query  = "UPDATE CMP.PEOPLE SET LOGIN_TS = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, LOGIN_ATT_NBR = LOGIN_ATT_NBR + 1 WHERE PRSN_ID='".$loginUserID."'";
            $result = mysql_query($query);
            $tes=mysql_fetch_array($result);
        }

       if($rows['LOGIN_ATT_NBR'] < 3){
            $warning    = "<font color='red'>Wrong Identity.</font><br />";
        }else if($rows['LOGIN_ATT_NBR'] == 3){
            $warning    = "<font color='red'>Delay 1 Minute</font><br />";
        }else if($rows['LOGIN_ATT_NBR'] == 4){
            $warning    = "<font color='red'>Delay 3 Minute</font><br />";
        }else if($rows['LOGIN_ATT_NBR'] == 5){
            $warning    = "<font color='red'>Delay 5 Minute</font><br />";
        }else{
            $warning    = "<font color='red'>Delay one day.</font><br />";
        }


 }else {
        $_SESSION['userID']=$loginUserID;
        $_SESSION['personNBR']=$row['PRSN_NBR'];
        $upperSec=getSecurity($loginUserID,"Executive");
        if (($upperSec==0)||(($upperSec<=8)&&($_COOKIE["DeviceAuth"]))) {
            $warning="<br/>";
            //Enforce hashing
                if($row['PWD']==$password){
                    $query="UPDATE CMP.PEOPLE SET LOGIN_TS = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, PWD='".hash('sha512',$password)."' WHERE PRSN_NBR=".$_SESSION['personNBR'];
                $result=mysql_query($query);   

                }
                if($rows['LOGIN_ATT_NBR'] >= 1){
                    $query  = "UPDATE CMP.PEOPLE SET LOGIN_TS = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, LOGIN_ATT_NBR = 0 WHERE PRSN_ID='".$loginUserID."'";
                     $result = mysql_query($query);
                }
                   header('Location:index.php'.$display);
exit;
}
else{
    $warning="<font color='red'>access can’t be reached .</font><br />";
    }
}}
```

Comment: You should always enable error logging. Then you would see that `AND TERM_DTE IS NULL".$time;` will give you a syntax error (there is a space missing between `null` and the `and` from `$time`). Also, generally: You are aware that everyone can just lock out everyone by just attempting to login as him, right? Usually, such system will use e.g. the ip to prevent this. Also, they will usually not increase the timeout if you attempt to login during the timeout (they will just ignore the attempt). Also: why do you query twice? You could just get the row for that user and evaluate it in php.